# Using Command Line in LibreCAD

Tags: cad

I am using `LibreCAD` and would like to run commands using the `Command Line Dock Widget`.

Have written the following commands in the `Command Line Entry`.

```
rectangle 0,0 34,55
Rectangle 0,0 34,55
RECTANGLE 0,0 34,55

rectangle 0,0 width 34 height 55
Rectangle 0,0 Width 34 Height 55
RECTANGLE 0,0 WIDTH 34 HEIGHT 55
```

After writing each command I press `Return` (`Enter`).  But nothing happens.  The rectangle is not shown.  What might I be doing wrong ?